# Check if URL has certain string and match position with PHP

Tags: php, url, strpos

I've tried the following:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (strpos($url,'austin') !== false) {
    echo 'Austin metro';
} else if (strpos($url,'georgetown') !== false) {
    echo 'Georgetown';
}
```

The issue is that this will match a URL that has **austin** anywhere. 
For example, the url for **georgetown** parameter is like this: www.domain.com/austin/georgetown/

So if url has austin/georgetown, would like to display georgetown option.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Why display `georgetown`?  Because it is listed after `austin` or what???

Comment: can you explain clearly, what result you want to get?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yeah basically im trying to deliver dynamic ads based on the url , some urls only have Austin like "www.domain.com/austin/story-test", so I will deliver Austin metro ads. But for Georgetown market, the url path is like www.domain.com/austin/georgetown/, so I will deliver Georgetown market ads.

Comment: @AmbrishPathak Hope that helps, let me know if still confusing. thanks

Comment: see my answer and let me know if it works for you @JoseSalazar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go like this:

```
$url = 'www.domain.com/austin/georgetown'; //output: georgetown

if  (strpos($url,'georgetown') !== false && strpos($url,'austin') !== false) 
{
    echo 'Georgetown';
} 
else if (strpos($url,'georgetown') !== false) 
{
    echo 'Georgetown';
} 
else if (strpos($url,'austin') !== false)
{
    echo 'austin';
}
```

first if condition is checking if austin and georgetown, both are there in the url, if yes georgetown will be printed. rest two conditions are just checking for austin and georgetown individually.

**See hear Php fiddle** -> https://eval.in/715874

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's a good start, the thing is that I have 7 additional markets, so the url variable value would have to change.

Comment: In case you need to know the market values: central-austin,leander-cedar-park, northwest-austin, round-rock-pflugerville-hutto, southwest-austin, san-marcos-buda-kyle, lake-travis-westlake

Comment: so what's the problem?, create conditional logic for all market values.